# merging 3 lists in ascending order

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to merge 3 sorted lists of ascending order without using any built-in functions or recursion. 
For example:

```
merge([1,4],[1,5,6],[3,7,9]) produces [1,1,3,4,5,6,7,9]
```

I have the following done so far but it does not produce the expected above result.

```
def merge(list1, list2, list3):
    results = []
    while len(list1) and len(list2) and len(list3):
        if (list1[0] < list2[0]) and (list1[0] < list3[0]):
            results.append(list1.pop(0))
        elif (list2[0] < list1[0]) and (list2[0] < list3[0]):
            results.append(list2.pop(0))
        elif (list3[0] < list1[0]) and (list3[0] < list2[0]):
            results.append(list3.pop(0))
    results.extend(list1)
    results.extend(list2)
    results.extend(list3)
    return results
```

Comment: see my simple solution

Comment: Cutie Pie in my last update eliminated the only builtin `len()` function, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `<` rather than `<=` is causing you problems. In the case where you have identical data points, it can easily lead to *none* of the `if` statements firing. Specifically, take your first data point from each list, `1/1/3`, and use them in the conditions for your three `if` statements:

```
(1 < 1) and (1 < 3): no, fails first part
(1 < 1) and (1 < 3): no, fails first part
(3 < 1) and (3 < 1): no, fails both parts
```

That causes an infinite loop since no action is being taken to modify the lists.

---

In any case, I think you're overly complicating things with a three-way merge when you can just do it as a couple of two-way merges:

```
def merge2(list1, list2):
    result = []
    idx1 = 0
    idx2 = 0

    # Get lowest while both lists are active.

    while idx1 < len(list1) and idx2 < len(list2):
        if list1[idx1] <= list2[idx2]:
            result.append(list1[idx1])
            idx1 += 1
        else:
            result.append(list2[idx2])
            idx2 += 1

    # Get remainder of each list (only one will be active here).

    while idx1 < len(list1):
        result.append(list1[idx1])
        idx1 += 1

    while idx2 < len(list2):
        result.append(list2[idx2])
        idx2 += 1

    return result

def merge(list1, list2, list3):
    # Three-way is two two-ways.

    return merge2(merge2(list1, list2), list3)

print(merge([1,4],[1,5,6],[3,7,9]))
```

This is *slightly* less efficient than a three-way but won't really make a difference unless you use truly *large* data sets (and, in my opinion, doing it this way results in a much "cleaner" program).

---

Of course the *smart* way to do this would be to use the actual facilities of the language. Even though you've stated you don't want to do that (and I'm not sure *why* that would be the case, other than maybe an artificial restriction for classwork), the Pythonic way would be:

```
def merge(list1, list2, list3):
    allitems = [item for sublist in [list1, list2, list3] for item in sublist]
    allitems.sort()
    return allitems
```

And, in fact, you could make it handle arbitrary list quantities by providing a list of lists in the call, rather than a fixed number of lists:

```
def merge(listOfLists):
    allitems = [item for sublist in listOfLists for item in sublist]
    allitems.sort()
    return allitems

print(merge([[1,4],[1,5,6],[3,7,9]])) # Three lists, but any number will work.
```

Comment: is there a way of doing this without any helper function?

Comment: @CutiePie, yes, there is. I call it the "ugly and not very well structured" method :-) In any case, *don't* think of it as a helper function, it's actually a useful two-way merge in its own right. Refactoring that out means you can use it in other situations.

Answer (score -1):

Or use non-builtin sorting way:

```
def merge(*l):
    l=[x for i in l for x in i]
    newl = []
    while l:
        mi = l[0]
        for x in l: 
            if x < mi:
                mi = x
        newl.append(mi)
        l.remove(mi)    

    return newl
```

Now:

```
print(merge([1,4],[1,5,6],[3,7,9]))
```

Is:

```
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

**Whithout any builtin function and so:**

a quite simple form:

```
def merge(*lists_in):
    list_in = []
    for l in lists_in:
        list_in += l

    i = 0
    while True:
    if i == list_in.__len__() -1:
        break
    if list_in[i] > list_in[i+1]:
        temp = list_in[i]
        list_in[i] = list_in[i+1]
        list_in[i+1] = temp
        i = 0
    else:
        i += 1

return list_in
```

**Testing it:**

```
list1 = [1,4] 
list2 = [1,5,6]
list3 = [3,7,9]

print(merge(list1, list2, list3))
```

**Out:**

```
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

Comment: There really is no need to do a sort when the whole point of a merge is to merge already-sorted data :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo haha, yeah

Comment: @paxdiablo with this update now using the merge() name is legal, but somone downvoted... :)